# Purescript compiles but js throws error : component.initialState is not a function

Tags: web-frontend, purescript, purescript-halogen

I'm building a simple video player component using `purescript-halogen`. The component is supposed to show a blank div with only an input button for the user to select a local file which will then act as a source URL for the video element.

I completed a working model in plain javascript and wanted to port it to purescript/halogen. I got the purescript version to compile but the web console gives me an error message `Uncaught TypeError: component.initialState is not a function` and points me to this MDN [reference](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Errors/Not_a_function).

This would suggest an issue with how I defined my initialState function but it's fairly standard:

```
component :: forall q i o m. MonadAff m => H.Component q i o m
component =
  H.mkComponent
    { initialState
    , render
    , eval: H.mkEval $ H.defaultEval { handleAction = handleAction }
    }

type State =
  { videoUrl :: Maybe String }

initialState :: forall i. i -> State
initialState _ =
  { videoUrl : Nothing
  }
```

Is it possible that the function is called at the wrong time during its lifecycle, hence making it undefined?

The code for the component is hosted on this Github [gist](https://gist.github.com/newton-migosi/988450dff99185703c5d6934f9d4364a). And I've been following this Github [issue](https://github.com/purescript-halogen/purescript-halogen/issues/612) as reference.

My `package.json` :

```
  "private": true,
  "devDependencies": {
    "parcel": "1.12.3",
    "purescript": "^0.14.0",
    "spago": "^0.19.1"
  },
  "scripts": {
    "build": "spago build",
    "test": "spago test",
    "serve": "parcel dev/index.html --open",
    "build-prod": "mkdir -p prod && cp dev/index.html prod/ && rm -rf dist && spago bundle-app --to prod/index.js && parcel build prod/index.html"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "node": "^15.12.0"
  }
}
```

I compiled using `purescript v0.14.0`, `spago v0.20.0`, `node v16.3.0` and tested on `Firefox v89.0` in `Ubuntu 20.04.2 LTS`.

Comment: Can you show the rest of the program? How is that component then used?

Comment: @FyodorSoikin I've given the full program in my answer, I guess in this instance the error message was misleading. The problem was with the render function rather than the initialState function.

Comment: the error in this context seems very strange anyway - my best guess is that the value somehow fires the changed-event at a time where the component is in some unknown state ... if this is really the case I think this should be considered a bug in Halogen - is there anyway you can get a really short version producing this error? Maybe just the file-input with a handler only logging or something and this value?

Answer (score 0):

Seems the bug is from a pesky line in the code:

```
HH.input 
  [ ...
  , HP.value "Select file"
  ...]
```

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/input/file#value), the `value` property of an input element is used to hold the path to the selected files. Therefore, setting it during element creation is not a well defined action.

The final code (which runs as expected) is:

```
module App.Video (component) where

import DOM.HTML.Indexed.InputAcceptType (InputAcceptType, InputAcceptTypeAtom(..))
import Data.Foldable (traverse_)
import Data.Maybe (Maybe(..))
import Data.MediaType (MediaType(..))
import Data.Traversable (for_)
import Effect.Aff.Class (class MonadAff)
import Halogen as H
import Halogen.HTML as HH
import Halogen.HTML.Events as HE
import Halogen.HTML.Properties as HP
import Prelude (Unit, bind, const, discard, pure, unit, ($), (=<<), (>>=))
import Web.Event.Event as Event

import Web.File.File as File
import Web.File.FileList as FileList
import Web.File.FileReader.Aff as FileReaderAff
import Web.HTML.HTMLInputElement as InputElement

data Action = HandleFileUpload Event.Event

type State =
  { videoUrl :: Maybe String }

component :: forall q i o m. MonadAff m => H.Component q i o m
component =
  H.mkComponent
    { initialState
    , render
    , eval: H.mkEval $ H.defaultEval { handleAction = handleAction }
    }

initialState :: forall input. input -> State
initialState inp =
  { videoUrl : Nothing
  }

render :: forall m slots. State -> H.ComponentHTML Action slots m
render state =
    case state.videoUrl of
        Nothing -> blank_player
        Just url -> video_player url

supported_formats :: InputAcceptType
supported_formats = 
    HP.InputAcceptType
        [ AcceptMediaType (MediaType "video/mp4")
        , AcceptMediaType (MediaType "video/webm")
        ]

blank_player :: forall w. HH.HTML w Action
blank_player = 
    HH.div_ 
        [ HH.span_ [HH.text "Choose file to upload"]
        , HH.input
            [ HP.type_ HP.InputFile
            , HP.accept supported_formats
            , HE.onChange HandleFileUpload
            ]
    ]

video_player :: forall w i. String -> HH.HTML w i
video_player url = 
    HH.div_ [
        HH.video [HP.src url] []
    ]

handleAction :: forall m slots o. MonadAff m => Action -> H.HalogenM State Action slots o m Unit 
handleAction = case _ of
  HandleFileUpload ev → do
    traverse_ handleFileUpload (InputElement.fromEventTarget =<< Event.target ev)

handleFileUpload :: forall m slots o. MonadAff m => InputElement.HTMLInputElement -> H.HalogenM State Action slots o m Unit 
handleFileUpload inputEl = do
  H.liftEffect (InputElement.files inputEl) >>= traverse_ \files ->
    for_ (FileList.item 0 files) \file → do
      video_url ← H.liftAff $ FileReaderAff.readAsDataURL (File.toBlob file)
      H.modify_ (const { videoUrl : Just video_url})
      pure unit
```